# Changing text size in CSS (HTML Webpage)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the font size in my HTML webpage, via CSS, but the "font-size" property doesn't seem to work:

Here's the HTML code for my webpage:
[image: Webpage Code]

And here's the very brief CSS code that goes with it:
[image: CSS Code]

Here's a picture of my webpage, with the VERY small text size, despite my font-size being set to 200px:

[image: Image of Webpage]

EDIT: No worries, here's the code:

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title> Flexbox in HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="/images/dog1.jpg"
            <p>This is dog 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="/images/dog2.jpg"
            <p>This is dog 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="/images/dog3.jpg"
            <p>This is dog 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="/images/dog4.jpg"
            <p>This is dog 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.inner img {
    height:50vh;
}

p {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 5000%;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste actual code instead of images?

Comment: Are you sure the css file is linked correctly?

Comment: Sorry about that, code posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't closed your `img` tags, which is making your `p` tags invalid. Add a `>` to the end of each of your images:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.inner img {
  height: 50vh;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="/images/dog1.jpg"><p>This is dog 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="/images/dog2.jpg"><p>This is dog 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="/images/dog3.jpg"><p>This is dog 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="/images/dog4.jpg"><p>This is dog 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag is not closed. So close it.
If you want a different font size in your Html element then use CSS selectors such as class, id, grouping, and universal.

For example:- Applying CSS class for paragraph element.

1. Demo.html

   ```
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="/images/dog1.jpg">
        <p class="paragraph-font">This is dog 1</p>
    </div>
   ```
2. Style.css

   ```
   .paragraph-font {
         font-size: 50px;
         }
   ```

In conclusion, you can give different font sizes according to your requirement by using CSS selectors. If you want to learn more then refer to this website.

Website link:- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp